# Drive API know when file is send to trash

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

I'm trying to know when a certain file is sent to the drive trash. I've tried the following but nothing seems to work:

```
@POST
@Path("/webhook")
public void webhook(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Credential credential = initFlow().loadCredential("user");
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

    String pageToken = GDrive.savedPageToken;
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("thread");
    log.setLevel(Level.INFO);

    while (pageToken != null) {
        ChangeList changes = service.changes().list(pageToken).execute();

        for (Change change : changes.getChanges()) {

            if  ( change.getFile() == null ) {
                log.info("IGNORE: "+change.getFileId());

            }
            else if (!change.getFile().getMimeType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.google-apps.folder")) {
                log.info("TRASHED REMOVE DIGITAL INPUT: "+change.getFile().getTrashed());
                log.info("TRASHED REMOVE DIGITAL INPUT: "+change.getRemoved());
                log.info("TRASHED REMOVE DIGITAL INPUT: "+change.getFile().getExplicitlyTrashed());
                log.info("TRASHED REMOVE DIGITAL INPUT: "+change.getFile().getName());
            }
        }
        if (changes.getNewStartPageToken() != null) {
            GDrive.savedPageToken = changes.getNewStartPageToken();
        }
        pageToken = changes.getNextPageToken();
    }
    response.setStatus(200);
}
```

The first condicion `change.getFile() == null` is for when file is completely removed from drive.

On the second one I try to see when a file is send to trash, but these functions `getTrashed()`, `getRemoved()`, `getExplicityTrashed()` are always null or false.

How I could know when a file is removed?

Comment: I don't undestand why I have to listen to files when I receive all of them on my webhook. How I can set X-Goog-Resource-State to trash?

Comment: Referring to the [Receiving notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#receiving-notifications), try setting X-Goog-Resource-State to [trash](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#responding-to-notifications) to listen to files which has been moved to the trash.

Comment: Try to play with the [pushnotifications playground](https://github.com/googledrive/pushnotifications-playground).

Comment: I've tested it several times. If you monitor all changes it just says "change", not trashed or added or anything else. And I'm not interested in monitoring an specific file.